# " If these questions don’t resolve your question, ask a new one. "

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

Here:

[Yet another Ajax POST to PHP: $_POST is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451273/yet-another-ajax-post-to-php-post-is-empty?noredirect=1#comment106941842_60451273)

I said I've already read other questions and they didn't solve my problem. Hence I asked a new question **linking** the relevant questions I read.

But I received downvotes and the question was closed, saying:

> If these questions don’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

That is *exactly* what I did.
Please, would you mind to explain why I'm wrong?

Comment: Caveat: I know nothing on Ajax and PHP. You link to the questions, which is great, but it helps if you explain why they don't help. Perhaps show your attempts at implementing them, and show why they fail, or show why they don't fit your needs. Note, however, that the linked duplicates aren't the ones in you reference in your question.

Comment: What I'm saying is it's odd to write "ask a new one" if it's what I've just done.

Comment: The prompt doesn't change just because you *have* asked a second question on the same problem if it's locked as a duplicate again.

Comment: So I'm wrong... ok. Question deleted - I apologize.

Comment: 'ask a new one' I believe means to ask a new question, not the same question again. Re structure the question, use different terms and scenarios to illustrate your problem and the things you've tried to find a solution.

Comment: It may help to realize that this message is automated - not something a human has written in response to your post. It's always shown when a question has been closed as a duplicate. If anyone has commented you might try communicating via comments to explain how the recommended answers don't help. Or edit the question with this information (very detailed, as explained by Larnu) which would put it in the re-open queue for re-evaluation.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I understand. But downvotes and an automated message that states what I've already said it's quite frustrating :)

Comment: @Mark There are several phrases that instantly trigger downvote reaction from anyone stayed on SO long enough: "searched for weeks", "tried a lot", "need this urgently" and yours "none of the answers solved my issue". Possibly people add them to questions to "demonstrate research" but none of such phrases does. Unless you want to have reasons to say "SO filled with @#$@" please avoid empty phrases like that and provide concrete details. "I tried {link to question} but it does not {exact details for your problem}" is far better than "{link to top rated question} doesn't @#$@ work".

Comment: Maybe the message text is not a good advice and should be changed. It rather means: either improve your question or put in some additional work and ask another question that demonstrates why you think it's not a duplicate.