# Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

The duplicate banner tells me:

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Should I keep reposting my question until I receive the answer I want? What should I do to the previous question? Delete it? Wouldn't this get me question-banned quicker?

If I ask a new question should I change something so that I have more chances of getting it answered instead of being closed with the same duplicate target?

Comment: Related question from someone who actually followed the advice. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394271/7795130

Comment: If this meta question gets closed as a duplicate should I ask it again?

Comment: Well, the duplicate banner will certainly invite you to.

Comment: `[faq-proposed]`?

Comment: IIRC, that isn't the duplicate banner, the duplicate banner links to how to ask, not the ask question page does it not?

Comment: @Nick I copied it verbatim from my own duplicate question. It's exactly that

Comment: Did you check the link though? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/you-can-edit-the-question-or-post-a-new-one - Or did you assume it took you to the ask a question form

Comment: @Nick I am not talking about closed questions, I am talking about duplicate ones. The banner leads me to the Ask a question page. The exact link is copied into this Meta question.

Comment: They seriously only edited the closed banner and not the duplicate banner? :facepalm: that's disappointing

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400960/12708583. FWIW, that advice is completely incorrect.

Comment: This is what started my meta-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174523/cannot-connect-to-mysql-database-on-localhost-using-pdo#comment113482251_64174523

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396474/8620333

Comment: @yivi Maybe, but that's not a good solution. The solution is to change the (repeatedly proven to be) misleading notice as requested countless times.

Comment: Posted this a few weeks ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400960/wording-of-guidance-for-op-on-a-duplicate-question

Comment: SIX TO EIGHT WEEKS.

Answer (score 30):

> Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?

#### No.

But unfortunately, the current wording (maybe by accident - don't know why they even thought about to choosing that) implies doing *exactly* that would be appropriate.

> "*If this question doesn’t resolve your question, **ask a new one**.*"

It suggests that if a duplicate question does not answer the question or resolve the issue of OP, they blatantly **should ask a new one** and with that not even showing in the slightest a little bit of information that, if reposted, **the question should be edited to shape**.

For me it is like saying "OK, you didn't got luck this time, but maybe next time it will be better. **Just try again**".

Beside the lack to hint that a new posted question should be edited to be distinct to the previous marked duplicate, in my humble opinion, the suggestion as whole to ask a new question is even more inappropriate.

We don't need even more garbage in the form of abandoned questions at the site.

**Curation instead of Re-Creation** is one of our highest community principles on Meta, but why is Stack Overflow itself working against that by suggesting so?

Edit the old closed question to be distinct from the duplicate, so that it can get reopened. That's the best way to keep Stack Overflow clear and stop the folks who clean up from madness.

---

I already made two answers to similar questions regarding the same topic, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400298/12139179) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400969/12139179).

These are the respective questions, which are related to this question:

- [Wording of guidance for OP on a duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400960/12139179)
- ["How do I ask a good question" page needs explicit statement "Don't repost your questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400273/12139179)

I hope that three answers of mine to that topic are enough now.

Comment: For some reasons, the "just try again" part made me badly laugh.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to an old question that isn't mine (in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048559/gwts-built-in-xsrf-protection ), aside from upvoting, that incorporates "I have the exact same problem now and it wasn't solved previously. Maybe 4 years later someone can shed new light on it." and resurfaces the question?

Answer (score 12):

Strictly speaking, the duplicate banner says that it's been associated with a *similar* question (not the exact same one). If it really is the exact same (or a nearly identical) question, it should not be posted. If someone is dissatisfied with the answers they got, they can always add a bounty to the existing question (or edit it to improve it to improve its chances of getting answered).

Repeatedly spamming the site with the same (or very similar) questions is [grounds for suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/#:%7E:text=A%20Day%20in%20the%20Penalty%20Box%20Are%20you,severe%20enough%20to%20merit%20outright%20expulsion%20from%20the%E2%80%A6).

That doesn't mean that it's completely against the rules to post a question that is similar to an existing one. Personally, if I post a question that I know is similar to an existing one, I link to it and explain how my question is different; that gives people more context, and it also helps to prevent people from getting confused and downvoting or voting to close.

Comment: If this were the case, then the banner is giving bad advice, which is probably the point of the question.

Comment: "*If someone is dissatisfied with the answers they got, they can always add a bounty to the existing question (or edit it to improve it to improve its chances of getting answered).*" - But where is that guidance in the banner?

Answer (score 10):

The banner says "ask a new one", not "ask the old one again".

The new question needs to be more clearly different from the "similar" question.   As EJoshuaS says, it might help to point out exactly how your new question is different from the "similar" question.

Comment: Why not edit the current one? What should I do to the old one? Should I delete as the UI suggests?

Comment: "*Ask a new one*" does not mean "*Ask a new question with cleared context to be distinct to the previous duplicate*".  It implies to just "ask a new (*formal*) question", saying it would be fine to keep the old content as it is, but just post it renewed. That's the point. Also posting a new question and abandon the old one is not good for Stack Overflow and the ones who clean the mess up.

Comment: @Dharman imagine an edit war between several people that want to make that one old question more specific and better suited for their cases. Then imagine what does that do with existing answers.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I wonder if OP was not referring to editing the one they created and which was closed as a duplicate, in an attempt to salvage it if it's not too late

Comment: Common language usage aside, a "question" in SE is a thing with its own page, possibly answer, comments, etc.  It's not surprising that saying "ask a new question" is being interpreted as "create another one of those things", and not "Create a different one of those things".

Answer (score -7):

> Should I keep reposting my question until I receive the answer I want?

No. Once might go unnoticed. Reposting the same question over and over to users who don't want to answer is not in your best interests.

> What should I do to the previous question? Delete it?

Depends. How much reputation do you currently have? How  many questions have you asked so far? How much are you willing to risk to get a answer to this question? Is a answer to this question that important to risk getting you question-banned? Do you want to keep adding questions here? If you have good reputation plus a couple of good  questions(questions with a score >= 1)  under your belt, the risk is low.

> If I ask a new question should I change something so that I have more chances of getting it answered instead of being closed with the same duplicate target?

You should definitely

- read the duplicate question(s) and **all** it's answers(not just the accepted one) and test each of them. Although the question might be different, any of the answers might work for your question. Maybe that's why it was considered a duplicate by the closers.

If you still believe "**None** of the answers" in the linked question answer your particular question,

- quote the duplicate question with it's link
- clearly explain why each of the answers(at least 2 to 3) won't/didn't work for your question

#### My personal suggestions:

Although the previous answers might recommend editing your original question, it is very rare for a question to be reopened after being closed. [Even if the question is completely different and you edit to make it clear, chances of getting your question reopened is really low](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402422/). Overall, It's around 2% in case of duplicates after question editing[<sup>stats</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last30days).

Deleting  and reasking after good research is the best way to go as far as getting a answer is concerned. It gives your question better exposure as well. Although you need to strive to make your new question clear and prove without doubt that it's not a duplicate, Some users comprehend better than others, question quality being the same. In other cases, there are burnt out users tired of seeing same questions over and over again, who might already be prejudiced.

> If you only review queue, you start to see only that, what is worse on StackOverflow. Every question is a potential candidate for close or downvote. Every asker a help vampire. It makes you burn out. I've also noticed that constant reviewing makes me more aggresive when it comes to downvoting and closing
>  - Danubian[<sup>link</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219609)

So, I think it's better to post a new question (at a different time of day or different day of week(weekends or weekdays) to avoid the same set of reviewers).

Comment: I'm sure some parts of the answer is controversial. But I hope it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure the recommendation in the last paragraph is sound. First, just because only 2% of *all duplicate closures* are re-opened does not mean that the chance of *well-edited duplicate closures* being re-opened is low. Second, from personal experience the volunteers likely to answer your questions are also likely to have seen *and voted on* the initial question. Trying to hide previous history and efforts does not signal cooperation. Treating volunteers like burnt out, prejudiced adversaries may well turn them into burnt out, prejudiced adversaries.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It is currently based on anecdotal evidence. I've been a asker, answerer and a burnt out close voter.  First, What are chances a new user is "able" to make a edit so as to get into the overall 2%? I think it's easier for a new user to just ask a new question.  Second, IMO, Most of them are already burnt out and prejudiced. I also think the quality of close review is very low and I'm sure the meta and socvr will disagree. And I currently disagree with both of them. Getting a question reopened is almost next to impossible even if you do all the right things.