# What is the policy on users deleting closed questions and asking them again repeatedly?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-accounts

I've encountered two users in the `[three.js]` tag who seem to be gaming the system to post duplicates of the same question. I've flagged this behavior with no resolution, so I'm not sure how to handle this situation. These two users asked the same question 3 times in the last 24 hours:

1. [three.js shader: How to make sphere ½ blue, ½ green](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70561298/three-js-shader-how-to-make-earth-atmosphere-have-half-blue-half-green)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70574192/three-js-earth-atmosphere-how-to-have-double-color
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577666/three-js-how-to-make-atmosphere-only-cover-half-of-earth

As you can see, questions #2, and #3 were getting downvoted and closed, so they were deleted by the author about an hour ago.

This has been going on for about a month now. Here is the duo posting duplicates back in `2021-Dec-17`:

1. [glsl three.js vertex and fragment shader not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390846/glsl-three-js-vertex-and-fragment-shader-not-working)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392083/three-js-animating-gltf-texture-using-shaders-error

And again on `2021-Dec-20`:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420695/threejs-vertex-and-fragment-shader-makes-gltf-model-and-texture-disappear
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417492/three-js-shader-not-appearing-on-gltf-model
3. [threejs glslshader not appearing on gltf model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430307/threejs-glslshader-not-appearing-on-gltf-model)
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70443883/three-js-gltf-model-shader-not-appearing

I've been downvoting/closing these duplicates for about a month, but they keep coming. I flagged this behavior back in December, but I didn't get any resolution because the user always deletes the question once it starts getting negative feedback. I think they're doing so to avoid detection, and it's working because the only way for me to pull up these examples was through my browser history; their profiles look clean and don't show any of the bad questions.

Should I simply keep closing/downvoting these duplicates, or is there a more direct way of dealing with this behavior? It's starting to show up daily.

Comment: Deleting a post won't affect any (custom) flag on it. Were your flags handled yet? Were they marked helpful?

Comment: Also, moderators can see all deleted posts in users' profiles.

Comment: @AdrianMole My flag (Raised Dec 20) is still pending: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2608515

Comment: Then just wait for the mods to get round to it. This Meta post may expedite that.

Comment: Deletion does not affect a moderator's ability to look up those questions. The mods just need to know to look at deleted posts. Did you describe the problem precisely in your original mod flag?

Comment: Deleting closed and downvoted questions may lead to the automatic question ban already. The bigger problem is the account deletion and recreation, which means they circumvented the ban, and this will usually get longer manual suspension imposed by a mod. (Well, unless the account deletion was done by the mod already)

Comment: Well, the company actually suggested to ask a new question when the old one got closed as a dupe (reported here: [Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401721)). I'm not surprised some still follow that advice even when their question got closed for a different reason.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah, I'm looking at the questions I posted, and it looks like the culprit accounts have been removed since I initially posted. Sounds like the SO policy is that this behavior is not allowed!

Comment: Re *"These two users asked the same question 3 times"*: Reading the text, yes. But the code is *completely* different. Is it really that clear cut?

Comment: Not long ago I pointed out a similar situation in a different tag. Unfortunately there isn’t much else you can do beside voting, mod-flagging and moving on. The “moving on” part is key. It’s not worth it to trade your own sanity for this kind of stuff.

Comment: When flagging for situations like this, even though mods *can* see deleted histories, it really helps to direct them with a custom flag explaining *everything* you observe with links and as much detail as possible; even if that means using something like pastebin or whatnot to expand on your notes. While it may work to some degree posting on meta this time, posting information about potential abuse (or sometimes user misunderstanding) like this isn't always fair to the user, privacy should be a priority where available.

Comment: That user seems to have resurfaced as *[stackoverflownumba1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17846908)*. There are several deleted questions before the one that is currently listed (I have the references. The questions are posted and then deleted if they don't get any answers). It is the same subject and the same kind of structure in the question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah, I’ve noticed that. Probably has deleted about 5 questions in its week of activity. It seems this person hasn’t learned a single thing. I also suspect [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709470/three-js-geometry-custom-vertical-hemisphere-180-degrees) might be a new account by the same individual, but it’s probably too early to tell. I guess the best course of action is to flag.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This isn't allowed on any SE site. Moderators have a canned message explicitly about this called "question repetition". There's a lot of reasons a user will re-ask the same question. Not all are malicious (sadly, the system tells you to "Ask a new question" in the close notice), but in this case, the pattern is pretty clear.

What you should do is raise a moderator flag on the most recent duplicate question and *include a link to prior duplicates*. The hallmark of bad behavior here is

- The user(s) has low (or no) reputation
- The questions are virtually identical

We've dealt with this user pretty decisively now, so hopefully the abuse stops, but keep flagging if it continues. We do dial things up as we go along to get them to stop.

Comment: I still don't understand why people read "ask a new question" as "ask the same question again in a new post". But the language in the close notice probably needs to be made more explicit.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Yeah, there's a whole Meta Q&A about that: [Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401721). "Ask a *different* question" would be somewhat better, but it would really take more words to make sure it can't be mis-read as ask the same question in a different/new post by people suffering from wishful thinking that they don't need to put any more effort in.

Comment: Seems like a stupid policy! What's wrong with asking the same question if the first time it didn't get any views or response? Second time around you will get different people viewing it and different responses(anecdotal evidence suggests that). Would you rather the person ask a question not get a response, lose faith in the site and never ask questions again?

Comment: @PeterChikov If a question doesn't get any answers (or answers that don't help you) we have the [bounty system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), which is like placing an ad on the site, except it uses reputation instead of money. As to why we don't allow repetition, [we're building a library of questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/2370483). It would be counterproductive to have answers strewn across half a dozen questions.

Comment: @Machavity Thank you for your response. Bounty system is good, but does not help new users. Building a library is a great cause and you have succeeded. If the question is deleted and re-asked, that does not detract from it. If the question is deleted, that means the answers were not good enough and should not be kept anyway. Maybe on the subsequent retry, the answers will be helpful and will get added to the library.

Comment: Uh-oh: "*We've dealt with this user pretty decisively now*". I like the sound of that! Thank you, @Machavity and company.

Answer (score 18):

Deleting a closed question and asking a radically improved version of it might be ok. But in general, deleting a closed question to ask the same identical question, or the same one with minor changes, is not acceptable behavior. Instead, the closed question should preferably get edited into shape and if found acceptable it will pass through re-open review.

If you encounter this behavior, the first time it is happening, just close as duplicate and explain in a comment to the user that they should fix their first post rather than re-posting it. If not possible (because posts were deleted), or if the user keeps persisting in posting the very same question over and over, flag one of the posts with a custom reason and explain the issue to the moderators. Provide links to all posts if possible (even if they are now deleted).

It will not matter if any of the posts are deleted, it will not affect the flag and moderators will still be able to see them, as will 10k+ rep users. Past 10k you can view deleted posts and you will even be able to flag deleted posts with the custom reason for diamond moderator attention.

Similarly, using "sock puppet" accounts to post the same question after the other account got suspended is also unacceptable and will only make things worse. Such situations should also get flagged for moderators.

In general, if you see an identical question getting posted by a different user, *always* flag with a custom flag for moderator attention. It might be a coincident, it might be sock puppets, it might be someone who tries to dodge a suspension. The mods will be able to tell and take action.

Comment: Note that deleted posts become visible at 10k (not 20k) ... but only if link to the post is available.

Comment: @AdrianMole Ah ok I might mix it up with delete votes.

Comment: Even for radical improvements, editing the question so that it can be re-opened would be preferable to creating a new question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller In theory yes. But if someone posts something in good faith, then it gets down voted to oblivion and they still want to try to improve it... then I don't blame them for deleting the down-voted post to start over. However, such deleted posts count to question ban though so it's probably not the best idea if you only have <10 posts total or so.

Comment: Does this Answer also apply to Qt1 = VLQ => gets downvoted (by me after 2 days to give User "a chance" to improve Quality), no Follow-up by User and (same) User opens Qt2 = Duplicate (a mini-mini-bit better Quality)...? // Example: Qt1: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535040/extract-data-from-a-div-class-with-imacros) + Qt2 (Duplicate): (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579868/data-from-a-div-class-with-divid). // I only have 0.5k-Rep, I can't VTC, only post Comments (+ downvoted both), but User is not "reacting"... (Both Qt's still "visible" at the time of posting...)

Comment: Empirically, this system does not work.

Answer (score 11):

The original [announcement of the introduction of suspensions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) *explicitly* lists this behavior as grounds for suspension:

> This user intentionally spams the site with the same question or very similar questions, over and over.

Answer (score -11):

This isn't "gaming the system"; it's a workaround for a severely broken system. Poorly structured questions are often closed within minutes, before the user even has an opportunity to see or act on feedback. Edited questions are almost never reopened because the moderation system is broken. If you're very lucky, the question ends up being answered in comments by the few remaining helpful users who were trying to clarify the question.

Comment: It's not the moderation system but the reopen queue is more or less out of function.  Having said that, a user should  research well before posting the question,  not after posting.

Comment: You would think that after that many attempts they would manage to edit it into a acceptable question **before** submitting it.

Comment: @DBS Many good questions are closed because people don't read or understand them; they see the subject and assume they know what the question is about. I had a question closed recently before I even saw the very first comment. One of the commenters realized about 20 comments into the conversation that the information they were asking for was in the original version of the question.

Comment: It is the communicator's job to make the presented information as accessible as possible. If too few people recognize the information the communicator has either either presented it poorly or presented it to the wrong audience. Sometimes it takes a few edits to get the question answerable, and in that case I'm with The Master: The review process is flawed.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70510200 by Edit 4, I think you have a fairly solid question.

Comment: @user4581301 Most questions have already been asked. Those that haven't are extremely esoteric. If one person understands the question, it's a good question. I've been on both sides of that kind of exchange.

Comment: Agreed, with quibbles. If it really is a duplicate, it should be closed as a duplicate and possibly a new answer added to the exiting question to cover any significant wrinkles posed by the question. If a duplicate is well-posed and researched, just missed the exiting duplicate, I'll probably upvote it even as I close it as a duplicate. It'll make good landing-and-redirect point, especially if it'll be easier to find than the question it duplicates. My definition of a good question is someone learns from it, even if they have to go to another castle to get the answer.

Comment: That the system in general struggles to deal with (initially) poor questions in a way that satisfies everyone has little to do with whether behavior such as the question describes is acceptable.  It is not.  And that the users in question have exhibited a history of deleting their poor question before posting a new copy shows that they *know* it isn't, and that they are trying to hide what they are doing.  "Gaming the system" fits those particulars fairly well.

Comment: Re *"...often closed within minutes, before the user even has an opportunity to see or act on feedback"*: Agreed. There ought to be one or more iterations, with an ***opportunity*** to improve a question, before answering and heavy-handed voting (incl. close voting and deletion). The current system is predicated on veteran users of [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) (or the equivalent) who know how to ask a good question without iteration, not the users of terrible, terrible forums (or the equivalent). There aren't many of the former, at least in relative terms.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly (or this answer, for that matter)... Even after a question has been closed, the user (question asker) still has an opportunity to improve the question, right? And closing _does_ create the opportunity to do that _before_ the question is answered, right? (If it's not closed, there's a good chance it will get bad answers, or good answers to the wrong question, both of which are bad for the site). So to me it seems like closing (and asking for clarity or whatever other form of improvement) is the right thing to do.

Comment: The closure message itself offers a form of feedback. Also, from my experience, people who delete and re-post questions rarely incorporate *any* of the feedback they were offered. I've often offered people detailed feedback and links explaining how to improve the question only to have the suggestions completely ignored.